# Aggregating an array of object field using mongoose - Rating calculation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a product model that looks thus:

```
{
   "name":"Natural Product",
   "ratings":[
      {
         "user":"5fdce4bd75dbe4864fcd5001",
         "rating":5
      },
      {
         "user":"5fdce4bd75dbe4864fcd5002",
         "rating":4
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried to get the average rating of the product model using the query below

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    _id: {$exists: true}
  }},
  {$group: {_id: "$_id", rating: { $avg: "$ratings.rating"}}}
])
```

But then the response I get looks thus:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60baf573246539ec265efd41"), "rating" : null }
```

While trying to figure what the problem is, I inserted a new dummy data  just with a slight difference in the structure that looks thus:

```
{
   "name":"Natural Product",
   "ratings":{
     "user": "5fdce4bd75dbe4864fcd5001",
     "rating": 5
   }
}
```

It gave me this reasonable response:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60bafb72246539ec265efd42"), "rating" : 5 }
```

How am I supposed to query the database to get the average of the ratings which is in array format, please?

Comment: add new stage after $match stage, `{ $unwind: "$ratings" }`, it will deconsturct the ratings array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$avg can be used in the $project stage if you have newer than mongodb server v3.2

```
db.products.aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            rating: { $avg: "$ratings.rating" }
        }
    }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/uehHGxI3ybU

Answer (score 1):

Doing this on array of objects is confusing. Mongo doesn't know which element to access in the array. So we need to `unwind` it in order to deconstruct it.
This will work

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$ratings"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      rating: {
        $avg: "$ratings.rating"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example for mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9eYNtv3CXZK)